# Encrypt data so that only the user can decrypt it in a Hybrid mobile app

Tags: cordova, angular, encryption, mobile, cryptography

I want to offer the user the option to encrypt all his/her files that are stored by my mobile app. It should be done in a way, so that not even the server can decrypt them - only the user itself.

It should work like [Mega](https://mega.nz/about) calls it:

> security by design ("we cannot gain access to your data without you
>   being able to find out")

In other words, like [WhatsApp](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/28030015) and all those other Chat Apps now state to use "End-to-End Encryption" just that there is only one Endpoint which is the client.

How can this be implemented for a mobile app? Preferably a Hybrid app using Ionic / Cordova / Angular.
As far as I understand, the encryption / decryption would have to run entirely on the client? 
But the difficult part is how can I make sure that really only the client can decrypt the files?

If someone could point me in the right direction that'd be great!

**Update:**
I found a short summary about how Mega supposedly does it:

> Because all the data is ciphered in the CLIENT (browser, app, etc), so
>   you send to Mega only the ciphered data. Mega doesn't have your
>   password or the original files, only the ciphered ones. They don't
>   even know the name of the files... The data is deciphered with your
>   account password, for that reason you can access the data from your
>   phone after login with your user AND pass.

https://www.reddit.com/r/MEGA/comments/2xkyt0/if_mega_does_not_hold_the_encryption_keys_to_my/

As far as I understand Mega would have to store the password of the user somewhere on client-side?

**Update 2:**
Mega offers a way to change the password: https://mega.nz/help/client/webclient/accounts-pro-accounts/how-do-i-change-my-password

How is that possible? Shouldn't all the already uploaded files be lost if the password is changed? Or all the file passwords are recalculated on client side at password change...

Comment: Simple symmetric encryption of the data which is then sent to the server and the key kept on the client-side should be good enough. This is how Mega works and this is what you could do. What's the issue here? Surely, you must have had the idea. *"But the difficult part is how can I make sure that really only the client has access?"* - Anybody can have access, but only the appropriate client can decrypt it.

Comment: What's the best way to keep this key on the client-side? What if the user uninstalls and reinstalls the app? Mega does it with the account password as a key (see Update in Question)... If the user forgets the password all data is lost.

Comment: That's right, if you want the data to be recoverable when something happens to the device, you either have to make clear to the user that they can trust you (terms & conditions) or make some hard usability choices like requiring the user to print out their key or something like that. Anyway, we're not anymore in the realm of programming at this point and your question would be off-topic.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I updated my question again. I don't see how this question is too broad. How could I possibly limit this question to a more specific problem? The follow up questions all refer to the same problem.

Comment: See this https://nzkoz.github.io/MegaPWN/ and this http://gizmodo.com/5978164/mega-is-going-to-handle-password-resets-different-than-everybody-else for some ideas how Mega handles this. TL;DR: it encrypts files with your own master key, and encrypts master key with your password. Both encrypted data and encrypted master key are stored on server side and decrypted on client side. Before changing password you need to backup master key and import it to keep master key the same and thus be able to access previously encrypted data. At least this gives false sense of security (as required).